# How can i set customize Form in add event of wdCalender?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, calendar

i want to set my own customize form in wdCalendar add event like first name last name instead of "what". where in jquery.calendar.js i find **quickadd**  function which one is used when user click on calendar to add event then form appear help of quickadd function but i dont know how to set custom field in this function so please help me

[image]

below one is quickadd function of jquery.calender.js

```
function quickadd(start, end, isallday, pos) {

            if ((!option.quickAddHandler && option.quickAddUrl == "") || option.readonly) {
                return;
            }
            var buddle = $("#bbit-cal-buddle");
            if (buddle.length == 0) {
                var temparr = [];
                temparr.push('<div id="bbit-cal-buddle" style="z-index: 180; width: 400px;visibility:hidden;" class="bubble">');
                temparr.push('<table class="bubble-table" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"><tbody><tr><td class="bubble-cell-side"><div id="tl1" class="bubble-corner"><div class="bubble-sprite bubble-tl"></div></div>');
                temparr.push('<td class="bubble-cell-main"><div class="bubble-top"></div><td class="bubble-cell-side"><div id="tr1" class="bubble-corner"><div class="bubble-sprite bubble-tr"></div></div>  <tr><td class="bubble-mid" colSpan="3"><div style="overflow: hidden" id="bubbleContent1"><div><div></div><div class="cb-root">');
                temparr.push('<table class="cb-table" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"><tbody><tr><th class="cb-key">');
                temparr.push(i18n.xgcalendar.time, ':</th><td class=cb-value><div id="bbit-cal-buddle-timeshow"></div></td></tr><tr><th class="cb-key">');
                temparr.push(i18n.xgcalendar.content, ':</th><td class="cb-value"><div class="textbox-fill-wrapper"><div class="textbox-fill-mid"><input id="bbit-cal-what" class="textbox-fill-input"/></div></div><div class="cb-example">');
                temparr.push(i18n.xgcalendar.example, '</div></td></tr></tbody></table><input id="bbit-cal-start" type="hidden"/><input id="bbit-cal-end" type="hidden"/><input id="bbit-cal-allday" type="hidden"/><input id="bbit-cal-quickAddBTN" value="');
                temparr.push(i18n.xgcalendar.create_event, '" type="button"/>&nbsp; <SPAN id="bbit-cal-editLink" class="lk">');
                temparr.push(i18n.xgcalendar.update_detail, ' <StrONG>&gt;&gt;</StrONG></SPAN></div></div></div><tr><td><div id="bl1" class="bubble-corner"><div class="bubble-sprite bubble-bl"></div></div><td><div class="bubble-bottom"></div><td><div id="br1" class="bubble-corner"><div class="bubble-sprite bubble-br"></div></div></tr></tbody></table><div id="bubbleClose1" class="bubble-closebutton"></div><div id="prong2" class="prong"><div class=bubble-sprite></div></div></div>');
                var tempquickAddHanler = temparr.join("");
                temparr = null;
                $(document.body).append(tempquickAddHanler);
                buddle = $("#bbit-cal-buddle");
                var calbutton = $("#bbit-cal-quickAddBTN");
                var lbtn = $("#bbit-cal-editLink");
                var closebtn = $("#bubbleClose1").click(function() {
                    $("#bbit-cal-buddle").css("visibility", "hidden");
                    realsedragevent();
                });
                calbutton.click(function(e) {
                    if (option.isloading) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    option.isloading = true;
                    var what = $("#bbit-cal-what").val();
                    var datestart = $("#bbit-cal-start").val();
                    var dateend = $("#bbit-cal-end").val();
                    var allday = $("#bbit-cal-allday").val();
                    var f = /^[^\$\<\>]+$/.test(what);
                    if (!f) {
                        alert(i18n.xgcalendar.invalid_title);
                        $("#bbit-cal-what").focus();
                        option.isloading = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                    var zone = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60 * -1;
                    var param = [{ "name": "CalendarTitle", value: what },
                        { "name": "CalendarStartTime", value: datestart },
                        { "name": "CalendarEndTime", value: dateend },
                        { "name": "IsAllDayEvent", value: allday },
                        { "name": "timezone", value: zone}];

                    if (option.extParam) {
                        for (var pi = 0; pi < option.extParam.length; pi++) {
                            param[param.length] = option.extParam[pi];
                        }
                    }

                    if (option.quickAddHandler && $.isFunction(option.quickAddHandler)) {
                        option.quickAddHandler.call(this, param);
                        $("#bbit-cal-buddle").css("visibility", "hidden");
                        realsedragevent();
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#bbit-cal-buddle").css("visibility", "hidden");
                        var newdata = [];
                        var tId = -1;
                        option.onBeforeRequestData && option.onBeforeRequestData(2);
                        $.post(option.quickAddUrl, param, function(data) {
                            if (data) {
                                if (data.IsSuccess == true) {
                                    option.isloading = false;
                                    option.eventItems[tId][0] = data.Data;
                                    option.eventItems[tId][8] = 1;
                                    render();
                                    option.onAfterRequestData && option.onAfterRequestData(2);
                                }
                                else {
                                    option.onRequestDataError && option.onRequestDataError(2, data);
                                    option.isloading = false;
                                    option.onAfterRequestData && option.onAfterRequestData(2);
                                }

                            }

                        }, "json");

                        newdata.push(-1, what);
                        var sd = strtodate(datestart);
                        var ed = strtodate(dateend);
                        var diff = DateDiff("d", sd, ed);
                        newdata.push(sd, ed, allday == "1" ? 1 : 0, diff > 0 ? 1 : 0, 0);
                        newdata.push(-1, 0, "", ""); 
                        tId = Ind(newdata);
                        realsedragevent();
                        render();
                    }
                });
                lbtn.click(function(e) {
                    if (!option.EditCmdhandler) {
                        alert("EditCmdhandler" + i18n.xgcalendar.i_undefined);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (option.EditCmdhandler && $.isFunction(option.EditCmdhandler)) {
                            option.EditCmdhandler.call(this, ['0', $("#bbit-cal-what").val(), $("#bbit-cal-start").val(), $("#bbit-cal-end").val(), $("#bbit-cal-allday").val()]);
                        }
                        $("#bbit-cal-buddle").css("visibility", "hidden");
                        realsedragevent();
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                buddle.mousedown(function(e) { return false });
            }

            var dateshow = CalDateShow(start, end, !isallday, true);            
            var off = getbuddlepos(pos.left, pos.top);
            if (off.hide) {
                $("#prong2").hide()
            }
            else {
                $("#prong2").show()
            }
            $("#bbit-cal-buddle-timeshow").html(dateshow);
            var calwhat = $("#bbit-cal-what").val("");
            $("#bbit-cal-allday").val(isallday ? "1" : "0");
            $("#bbit-cal-start").val(dateFormat.call(start, i18n.xgcalendar.dateformat.fulldayvalue + " HH:mm"));
            $("#bbit-cal-end").val(dateFormat.call(end, i18n.xgcalendar.dateformat.fulldayvalue + " HH:mm"));
            buddle.css({ "visibility": "visible", left: off.left, top: off.top });          
            calwhat.blur().focus(); //add 2010-01-26 blur() fixed chrome 
            $(document).one("mousedown", function() {
                $("#bbit-cal-buddle").css("visibility", "hidden");
                realsedragevent();
            });
            return false;
        }
```

could i add ajax link on add event and display custom form and add data to database ?
is there any solution of this type to direct open popup as in add event as like open in edit event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And Here we go..

just copy paste this code in your jquery.form.js

it will provide you and extra field to input text.

**jquery.form.js**

```
<script>
    (function($) {
    $.fn.ajaxSubmit = function(options) {  
        if (!this.length) {
            log('ajaxSubmit: skipping submit process - no element selected');
            return this;
        }

        if (typeof options == 'function')
            options = { success: options };

        options = $.extend({
            url:  this.attr('action') || window.location.toString(),
            type: this.attr('method') || 'GET'
        }, options || {});

        var veto = {};
        this.trigger('form-pre-serialize', [this, options, veto]);
        if (veto.veto) {
            log('ajaxSubmit: submit vetoed via form-pre-serialize trigger');
            return this;
        }

        if (options.beforeSerialize && options.beforeSerialize(this, options) === false) {
            log('ajaxSubmit: submit aborted via beforeSerialize callback');
            return this;
        }    

        var a = this.formToArray(options.semantic);
        if (options.data) {
            options.extraData = options.data;
            for (var n in options.data) {
              if(options.data[n] instanceof Array) {
                for (var k in options.data[n])
                  a.push( { name: n, value: options.data[n][k] } )
              }  
              else
                 a.push( { name: n, value: options.data[n] } );
            }
        }

        if (options.beforeSubmit && options.beforeSubmit(a, this, options) === false) {
            log('ajaxSubmit: submit aborted via beforeSubmit callback');
            return this;
        }    


        this.trigger('form-submit-validate', [a, this, options, veto]);
        if (veto.veto) {
            log('ajaxSubmit: submit vetoed via form-submit-validate trigger');
            return this;
        }    

        var q = $.param(a);

        if (options.type.toUpperCase() == 'GET') {
            options.url += (options.url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + q;
            options.data = null;  
        }
        else
            options.data = q;

        var $form = this, callbacks = [];
        if (options.resetForm) callbacks.push(function() { $form.resetForm(); });
        if (options.clearForm) callbacks.push(function() { $form.clearForm(); });

        if (!options.dataType && options.target) {
            var oldSuccess = options.success || function(){};
            callbacks.push(function(data) {
                $(options.target).html(data).each(oldSuccess, arguments);
            });
        }
        else if (options.success)
            callbacks.push(options.success);

        options.success = function(data, status) {
            for (var i=0, max=callbacks.length; i < max; i++)
                callbacks[i].apply(options, [data, status, $form]);
        };

        var files = $('input:file', this).fieldValue();
        var found = false;
        for (var j=0; j < files.length; j++)
            if (files[j])
                found = true;

       if (options.iframe || found) { 
           if ($.browser.safari && options.closeKeepAlive)
               $.get(options.closeKeepAlive, fileUpload);
           else
               fileUpload();
           }
       else
           $.ajax(options);
        this.trigger('form-submit-notify', [this, options]);
        return this;

        function fileUpload() {
            var form = $form[0];

            if ($(':input[@name=submit]', form).length) {
                alert('Error: Form elements must not be named "submit".');
                return;
            }

            var opts = $.extend({}, $.ajaxSettings, options);
            var s = jQuery.extend(true, {}, $.extend(true, {}, $.ajaxSettings), opts);

            var id = 'jqFormIO' + (new Date().getTime());
            var $io = $('<iframe id="' + id + '" name="' + id + '" />');
            var io = $io[0];

            if ($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera) 
                io.src = 'javascript:false;document.write("");';
            $io.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '-1000px', left: '-1000px' });

            var xhr = { 
                aborted: 0,
                responseText: null,
                responseXML: null,
                status: 0,
                statusText: 'n/a',
                getAllResponseHeaders: function() {},
                getResponseHeader: function() {},
                setRequestHeader: function() {},
                abort: function() { 
                    this.aborted = 1; 
                    $io.attr('src','about:blank'); 
                }
            };

            var g = opts.global;

            if (g && ! $.active++) $.event.trigger("ajaxStart");
            if (g) $.event.trigger("ajaxSend", [xhr, opts]);

            if (s.beforeSend && s.beforeSend(xhr, s) === false) {
                s.global && jQuery.active--;
                return;
            }
            if (xhr.aborted)
                return;

            var cbInvoked = 0;
            var timedOut = 0;

            var sub = form.clk;
            if (sub) {
                var n = sub.name;
                if (n && !sub.disabled) {
                    options.extraData = options.extraData || {};
                    options.extraData[n] = sub.value;
                    if (sub.type == "image") {
                        options.extraData[name+'.x'] = form.clk_x;
                        options.extraData[name+'.y'] = form.clk_y;
                    }
                }
            }

            setTimeout(function() {
                var t = $form.attr('target'), a = $form.attr('action');
                $form.attr({
                    target:   id,
                    method:   'POST',
                    action:   opts.url
                });

                if (! options.skipEncodingOverride) {
                    $form.attr({
                        encoding: 'multipart/form-data',
                        enctype:  'multipart/form-data'
                    });
                }


                if (opts.timeout)
                    setTimeout(function() { timedOut = true; cb(); }, opts.timeout);

                var extraInputs = [];
                try {
                    if (options.extraData)
                        for (var n in options.extraData)
                            extraInputs.push(
                                $('<input type="hidden" name="'+n+'" value="'+options.extraData[n]+'" />')
                                    .appendTo(form)[0]);

                    $io.appendTo('body');
                    io.attachEvent ? io.attachEvent('onload', cb) : io.addEventListener('load', cb, false);
                    form.submit();
                }
                finally {        
                    $form.attr('action', a);
                    t ? $form.attr('target', t) : $form.removeAttr('target');
                    $(extraInputs).remove();
                }
            }, 10);

            function cb() {
                if (cbInvoked++) return;

                io.detachEvent ? io.detachEvent('onload', cb) : io.removeEventListener('load', cb, false);

                var operaHack = 0;
                var ok = true;
                try {
                    if (timedOut) throw 'timeout';

                    var data, doc;

                    doc = io.contentWindow ? io.contentWindow.document : io.contentDocument ? io.contentDocument : io.document;

                    if (doc.body == null && !operaHack && $.browser.opera) {                  
                        operaHack = 1;
                        cbInvoked--;
                        setTimeout(cb, 100);
                        return;
                    }

                    xhr.responseText = doc.body ? doc.body.innerHTML : null;
                    xhr.responseXML = doc.XMLDocument ? doc.XMLDocument : doc;
                    xhr.getResponseHeader = function(header){
                        var headers = {'content-type': opts.dataType};
                        return headers[header];
                    };

                    if (opts.dataType == 'json' || opts.dataType == 'script') {
                        var ta = doc.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
                        xhr.responseText = ta ? ta.value : xhr.responseText;
                    }
                    else if (opts.dataType == 'xml' && !xhr.responseXML && xhr.responseText != null) {
                        xhr.responseXML = toXml(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                    data = $.httpData(xhr, opts.dataType);
                }
                catch(e){
                    ok = false;
                    $.handleError(opts, xhr, 'error', e);
                }

                if (ok) {
                    opts.success(data, 'success');
                    if (g) $.event.trigger("ajaxSuccess", [xhr, opts]);
                }
                if (g) $.event.trigger("ajaxComplete", [xhr, opts]);
                if (g && ! --$.active) $.event.trigger("ajaxStop");
                if (opts.complete) opts.complete(xhr, ok ? 'success' : 'error');

                // clean up
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $io.remove();
                    xhr.responseXML = null;
                }, 100);
            };

            function toXml(s, doc) {
                if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                    doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                    doc.async = 'false';
                    doc.loadXML(s);
                }
                else
                    doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(s, 'text/xml');
                return (doc && doc.documentElement && doc.documentElement.tagName != 'parsererror') ? doc : null;
            };
        };
    };

    $.fn.ajaxForm = function(options) {
        return this.ajaxFormUnbind().bind('submit.form-plugin',function() {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
            return false;
        }).each(function() {      
            $(":submit,input:image", this).bind('click.form-plugin',function(e) {
                var form = this.form;
                form.clk = this;
                if (this.type == 'image') {
                    if (e.offsetX != undefined) {
                        form.clk_x = e.offsetX;
                        form.clk_y = e.offsetY;
                    } else if (typeof $.fn.offset == 'function') { // try to use dimensions plugin
                        var offset = $(this).offset();
                        form.clk_x = e.pageX - offset.left;
                        form.clk_y = e.pageY - offset.top;
                    } else {
                        form.clk_x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                        form.clk_y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                    }
                }
                // clear form vars
                setTimeout(function() { form.clk = form.clk_x = form.clk_y = null; }, 10);
            });
        });
    };

    $.fn.ajaxFormUnbind = function() {
        this.unbind('submit.form-plugin');
        return this.each(function() {
            $(":submit,input:image", this).unbind('click.form-plugin');
        });

    };

    $.fn.formToArray = function(semantic) {
        var a = [];
        if (this.length == 0) return a;

        var form = this[0];
        var els = semantic ? form.getElementsByTagName('*') : form.elements;
        if (!els) return a;
        for(var i=0, max=els.length; i < max; i++) {
            var el = els[i];
            var n = el.name;
            if (!n) continue;

            if (semantic && form.clk && el.type == "image") {
                // handle image inputs on the fly when semantic == true
                if(!el.disabled && form.clk == el)
                    a.push({name: n+'.x', value: form.clk_x}, {name: n+'.y', value: form.clk_y});
                continue;
            }

            var v = $.fieldValue(el, true);
            if (v && v.constructor == Array) {
                for(var j=0, jmax=v.length; j < jmax; j++)
                    a.push({name: n, value: v[j]});
            }
            else if (v !== null && typeof v != 'undefined')
                a.push({name: n, value: v});
        }

        if (!semantic && form.clk) {
            // input type=='image' are not found in elements array! handle them here
            var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i=0, max=inputs.length; i < max; i++) {
                var input = inputs[i];
                var n = input.name;
                if(n && !input.disabled && input.type == "image" && form.clk == input)
                    a.push({name: n+'.x', value: form.clk_x}, {name: n+'.y', value: form.clk_y});
            }
        }
        return a;
    };

    $.fn.formSerialize = function(semantic) {
        return $.param(this.formToArray(semantic));
    };

    $.fn.fieldSerialize = function(successful) {
        var a = [];
        this.each(function() {
            var n = this.name;
            if (!n) return;
            var v = $.fieldValue(this, successful);
            if (v && v.constructor == Array) {
                for (var i=0,max=v.length; i < max; i++)
                    a.push({name: n, value: v[i]});
            }
            else if (v !== null && typeof v != 'undefined')
                a.push({name: this.name, value: v});
        });
        return $.param(a);
    };


    $.fn.fieldValue = function(successful) {
        for (var val=[], i=0, max=this.length; i < max; i++) {
            var el = this[i];
            var v = $.fieldValue(el, successful);
            if (v === null || typeof v == 'undefined' || (v.constructor == Array && !v.length))
                continue;
            v.constructor == Array ? $.merge(val, v) : val.push(v);
        }
        return val;
    };

    $.fieldValue = function(el, successful) {
        var n = el.name, t = el.type, tag = el.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (typeof successful == 'undefined') successful = true;

        if (successful && (!n || el.disabled || t == 'reset' || t == 'button' ||
            (t == 'checkbox' || t == 'radio') && !el.checked ||
            (t == 'submit' || t == 'image') && el.form && el.form.clk != el ||
            tag == 'select' && el.selectedIndex == -1))
                return null;

        if (tag == 'select') {
            var index = el.selectedIndex;
            if (index < 0) return null;
            var a = [], ops = el.options;
            var one = (t == 'select-one');
            var max = (one ? index+1 : ops.length);
            for(var i=(one ? index : 0); i < max; i++) {
                var op = ops[i];
                if (op.selected) {
                    var v = $.browser.msie && !(op.attributes['value'].specified) ? op.text : op.value;
                    if (one) return v;
                    a.push(v);
                }
            }
            return a;
        }
        return el.value;
    };

    $.fn.clearForm = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $('input,select,textarea', this).clearFields();
        });
    };


    $.fn.clearFields = $.fn.clearInputs = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var t = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (t == 'text' || t == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
                this.value = '';
            else if (t == 'checkbox' || t == 'radio')
                this.checked = false;
            else if (tag == 'select')
                this.selectedIndex = -1;
        });
    };


    $.fn.resetForm = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
           if (typeof this.reset == 'function' || (typeof this.reset == 'object' && !this.reset.nodeType))
                this.reset();
        });
    };

    $.fn.enable = function(b) { 
        if (b == undefined) b = true;
        return this.each(function() { 
            this.disabled = !b 
        });
    };


    $.fn.selected = function(select) {
        if (select == undefined) select = true;
        return this.each(function() { 
            var t = this.type;
            if (t == 'checkbox' || t == 'radio')
                this.checked = select;
            else if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'option') {
                var $sel = $(this).parent('select');
                if (select && $sel[0] && $sel[0].type == 'select-one') {
                    // deselect all other options
                    $sel.find('option').selected(false);
                }
                this.selected = select;
            }
        });
    };


    function log() {
        if ($.fn.ajaxSubmit.debug && window.console && window.console.log)
            window.console.log('[jquery.form] ' + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,''));
    };
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```